# GitLab block merge request if maintainer doesn't perform a code review and complete checklist

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I am trying to set up a GitLab workflow for my project.
When someone writes on a feature branch and completes that task, that person creates a merge request.

In our team, we have created a checklist that represents the definition of done.

So when someone creates a merge request, one of the other developers has to do a code review and check all the items on the checklist.

Are there any tools for GitLab that will automatically comment the merge request and display the checklist in the comment. Also, the merge request should be blocked until another developer checks off all the items on the list?

We are a university research group and use a free version of the self-hosted GitLab instance with version 14.9.1